# how can I save an NSImageView layer to a PNG on disk?

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, nsdata, nsimage

I'm trying to do the following batch processing:

1. load an image
2. scale it
3. add a rounded border to it
4. save the new
       image as PNG

So far, I came up with this:

```
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.window.frame.size.width / 2., self.window.frame.size.height / 2.);
      [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationHigh];
      NSImage * newThumbnail = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[files objectAtIndex:0]]];
      NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(center.x - (57/2.), center.y - (80/2.), 57, 80)];
      [imageView setWantsLayer:YES];

      imageView.layer.borderColor = [[NSColor blackColor] CGColor];
      imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
      imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
      imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
      imageView.image = newThumbnail;
```

And now I think I'm missing telling the layer to redender to some context?
maybe something like `[imageView.layer drawInContext: some context (NS o CG?)];` and saving that context to disk. But I'm confused as to:

what context,

whether to go from context to NSData to disk,

or if I need an intermediate image somewhere before saving.

Basically, between CALayers and CGLayers and NS objects and UI objects (I know I'm in OS X Cocoa here and it's no UIKit and I'm also not using CG stuff so far) I have no idea how to turn the above into a png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a view at all, since you're not needing to display to screen. You should be using an offscreen bitmap (an `NSBitmapImageRep`) and using drawing commands to draw the image.

You have two choices with drawing in Cocoa. The easiest way is to use the various Cocoa drawing classes such as `NSBezierPath` and friends. The other option is the more powerful but also more low-level and complex Quartz APIs, which are not object-oriented but use a C function syntax.

Here is an example of how to do what you want using Cocoa drawing:

```
NSImage* anImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Lenna.tiff"]; //or some other source

//create a bitmap at a specific size
NSRect offscreenRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 250.0, 250.0);
NSBitmapImageRep* bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:nil
                                                       pixelsWide:offscreenRect.size.width
                                                       pixelsHigh:offscreenRect.size.height
                                                    bitsPerSample:8
                                                  samplesPerPixel:4
                                                         hasAlpha:YES
                                                         isPlanar:NO
                                                   colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
                                                     bitmapFormat:0
                                                      bytesPerRow:(4 * offscreenRect.size.width)
                                                     bitsPerPixel:32];

//save the current graphics context and lock focus on the bitmap
NSGraphicsContext* originalContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:[NSGraphicsContext
                                      graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:bitmap]];
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

//clear the image rep. This is faster than filling with [NSColor clearColor].
unsigned char *bitmapData = [bitmap bitmapData];
if (bitmapData)
    bzero(bitmapData, [bitmap bytesPerRow] * [bitmap pixelsHigh]);

//create the border path
CGFloat borderWidth = 2.0;
CGFloat cornerRadius = 14.0;
NSRect borderRect = NSInsetRect(offscreenRect, borderWidth/2.0, borderWidth/2.0);
NSBezierPath* border = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:borderRect xRadius:cornerRadius yRadius:cornerRadius];
[border setLineWidth:borderWidth];

//set the border as a clipping path
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
[border addClip];

//scale and draw the image
[anImage setSize:offscreenRect.size];
[anImage drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

//set the border color
[[NSColor blackColor] set];

//draw the border
[border stroke];

//restore the original graphics context
[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:originalContext];

//get PNG data from the image rep
NSData* pngData = [bitmap representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
NSError* error;
if(![pngData writeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png"]] options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

Comment: actually I might go for the Quartz approach since it's more like OpenGL which I'm more comfortable with. But this way works too. Thanks!